# Not sure how to hide/show a specific divider based on a PHP variable

Tags: php, html, css

I've been trying to show a display a specific divider if a variable is true. So let me just show you what I've got so far and hopefully someone will be willing to help.

This is the check that should be performed when the A HREF is clicked:

```
<?php
function enter_username_phase() {
    if (isset($_POST['package'])) {
        $package = $_POST['package']);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}?>
```

Now this is the one of the buttons which will send the package id:

```
<a href='#credits?package=1'>
    <div class="box">
        <font size="4"><b>Price</b></font><br>Amount<br>
    </div>
</a>
```

Here's the method I use to check if the variable is shown along with the div I'd like to display:

```
<style>
    #enter_username {
        <?php
            if (enter_username_phase()) {
                echo 'display:block;';
            }
        ?>
    }
</style>

<div class="enter_username">
    <center>
    <br>
    <form name="username" method="post" action="#credits">
        <INPUT type="username" name="username" maxlength="16">
        <INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name="Submit" VALUE = "Check username">
    </form>
    <br><br>
    </center>
</div>
```

And this is the divider's definition in the css file:

```
.enter_username {
    display: none;
}
```

I'm assuming I'm going wrong either the way I'm displaying having the element displayed or it's not working because there is nothing that triggers this check, perhaps I need to force a refresh or an update of the page I'm really not sure. I'd like to stick to PHP/CSS/HTML methods to have this done. If anyone is willing to help me I'd really appreciate it, thank you very much for your time and happy holidays.

Answer (score 0):

You are using $_POST method there, but you should use $_GET method. Use this code:

```
<?php
   function enter_username_phase() {
       if (isset($_GET['package'])) {
       $package = $_GET['package']);
       return true;
   } else {
       return false;
   }
}?>
```

Then it will work..

Comment: You forgot to change $_POST to $_GET ;)

Comment: I just tried changing the post to a get method and it made no difference. Do I have to maybe update the page somehow so that it'll show the divider after it's clicked now?

Comment: sorry, my bad.. I have updated the code, check again please.

Comment: It makes no difference unfortunately, thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a css class that hides the element:

```
<style>
    .hidden { display: none; }
</style>
```

Then conditionally add this class to your element:

```
<div class="enter_username<?php if (enter_username_phase()) { echo " hidden"; } ?>>
```

There are more graceful ways of implementing this, but I'd caution against changing your styles based on application logic.  Also, in your styles, #enter_username refers to an id, not a class.  You'd apply the style to .enter_username if you wanted to target a class.

Comment: I adjusted the enter_username and I already have a css class that sets the display to none, it's at the bottom of the post, is it not good the way its done?

Comment: The .enter_username class should style that element for when it is shown.  What you're looking to do is conditionally modify the overall page by hiding that element.  You can accomplish this by adding an additional style to .enter_username that modifies its appearance without changing the style you've defined.  (If you're not aware, you can add multiple css classes to an element, just separate them with spaces)